# Safari 13.0.4 issue with PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, redirect, cookies, safari

I'm running a PHP script (on DOMAIN B) inside an iFrame on another domain (DOMAIN A).
When a user enters the site, a check is performed to see if they have the correct browser settings (cookies enabled AND third-party cookies enabled - however it is called in various browsers).

In order to do this, I set a session cookie `$_SESSION['COOKIE_CHECK'] = 'passed';` from the iFrame (DOMAIN B), redirect to another script within the iFrame on DOMAIN B (`header('Location: ...`) and check if the cookie is still there. If not, an error message is displayed, otherwise the user is redirected again to the main script (also on DOMAIN B).

I'm making sure the session is active with `session_start();` as the first line of code in all scripts. The header redirect is using the same (sub)domain for the target as the originating script.

This worked perfectly fine on all browsers (IE, FF, Safari, Chrome) for years until now. With the recent Safari update to version 13.0.4, this no longer works in Safari. It still works in other browsers.

I tried a few things including redirecting the parent document to the cookie check script on DOMAIN B and then back again. Nothing worked.

Any insight would greatly be appreciated!

Cheers and thanks in advance!
Tom

Comment: There appears to be a bug with Safari 13.0.4 and cookies/iframes: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206643